# Can a char array of pointers store a string?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, implicit-conversion

I was studying pointer in C to array. Everything was fine, until I came across this code. `*names` is array of pointers, which should store those addresses that points to char, but it stores a string. Can someone explain this to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 4;

int main () {
    char *names[] = {
        "Zara Ali",
        "Hina Ali",
        "Nuha Ali",
        "Sara Ali"
    };
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 Value of names[0] = Zara Ali
 Value of names[1] = Hina Ali
 Value of names[2] = Nuha Ali
 Value of names[3] = Sara Ali
```

Comment: It is storing pointers.... The strings (string literals) are located in some memory outside `names`. The compiler takes care of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
char *names[] = {
  "Zara Ali",
  "Hina Ali",
  "Nuha Ali",
  "Sara Ali"
};
```

declares names to be an array of pointers to `char`, and initializes its elements with the addresses of the first elements of the four strings.

A string enclosed in double quotes is a short-hand way of writing a pointer to a nameless array that has been initialized with the characters between the quotes and an extra null-byte which marks the end of the string.

> names is array of pointer which should store those address that points to char but it stores string.

Yes, indeed. It is an array of pointers to `char`s, not pointes to strings, and it's elements are pointing to the first element of the strings, which are `char`s.

In memory, the first element of the array will look something like this:

```
          +-------+
names[0]: |   *   |
          +---|---+
              |
              V
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+
            |'Z'|'a'|'r'|'a'|' '|'A'|'l'|'i'|'\0'|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+--+----+
```

Note that this memory is immutable, i.e. you can change the pointer to point somewhere else, but you may not change the pointed to data. Otherwise, your code would invoke undefined behaviour. And for this reason, it is always better to declare pointers to string literals with the `const` qualifier:

```
const char *names[] = {
  "Zara Ali",
  "Hina Ali",
  "Nuha Ali",
  "Sara Ali"
};
```

Using `const` helps retain the string's integrity because you can only modify it with a new pointer to the string or by passing it to a function which modifies the string.

Comment: thanks for such detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
   char *names[] = {
  "Zara Ali",
  "Hina Ali",
  "Nuha Ali",
  "Sara Ali"
    };
```

the string literals having the array type `char[9]` and static storage duration used as initializers are implicitly converted to pointers of the type `char *` to their first elements.

You may even equivalently write

```
   char *names[] = {
  &"Zara Ali"[0],
  &"Hina Ali"[0],
  &"Nuha Ali"[0],
  &"Sara Ali"[0]
    };
```

Pay attention to that for example the string literal `"Zara Ali"` is stored in memory as an array like

```
{ 'Z', 'a', 'r', 'a', ' ', 'A', 'l', 'i', '\0' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of string literal is char[N].
But unless an array is used with *&* or *sizeof* operator, it gets converted into a pointer that points at its element.
So, if you write `char *str = "Hello, World!"`  the actual type of "Hello, World!" is char[14] and it is stored somewhere in the memory.
But it gets converted into char* at initialization of str

Answer (score 1):

It is storing pointers.... The strings (string literals) are located in some memory outside `names`. The compiler takes care of that.

You can think of code like this code:

```
  // Strings as global variables
  char str1[] = "Zara Ali";
  char str2[] = "Hina Ali";
  char str3[] = "Nuha Ali";
  char str4[] = "Sara Ali";
    
 int main () {

    char *names[] = {
        &str1[0],     // Storing pointers
        &str2[1],
        &str3[2],
        &str4[3]
    };
```

Here the 4 strings are obviously stored in other memory than `names` and `names` holds pointers to the first character of the strings.

When you do

```
    char *names[] = {
  "Zara Ali",
  "Hina Ali",
  "Nuha Ali",
  "Sara Ali"
    };
```

it's kind of the same that goes on. The compiler just handle it behind the scenes.

BTW:

Since you have an array of pointers you can do:

```
char *names[] = {
  "Zara Ali",
  "Hina Ali",
  "Nuha Ali",
  "Sara Ali"
};
size_t MAX = sizeof names / sizeof names[0];
```

instead of the hardcode `const int MAX = 4;`. Then `MAX` will automatically get the correct value when a new string is added to the array.